# Radio button checked dot is not coming in center

Tags: html, css, radio-button

My Radio button's checked dot is not coming in center if radio option is checked.

Please find my fiddle below:

```css
/* checkbox -*/

.radio-s label,
.radio-s input[type="radio"]+span,
.radio-s input[type="radio"]+span::after,
.checkboxe-s label,
.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]+span,
.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]+span::after {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.radio-s,
.checkboxe-s {
  position: relative
}

.radio-s label *,
.checkboxe-s label * {
  cursor: pointer
}

.radio-s input[type="radio"],
.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  display: none
}

.radio-s input[type="radio"]+span,
.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]+span {
  color: #333
}

.radio-s label:hover span,
.checkboxe-s label:hover span {
  color: #000
}

.radio-s input[type="radio"]+span::after,
.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]+span::after {
  margin: 0 auto 0 10px;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border: solid 2px #ccc;
  background-size: 13px;
  content: "";
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 17px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*display: block;*/
}

.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]+span:hover::after {
  border: solid 2px #5a5a5a
}

.radio-s input[type="radio"]:checked+span::after,
.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span::after {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border: 2px solid #01A982;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #01A982;
  line-height: 17px
}

.radio-s input[type="radio"]:disabled+span,
.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+span {
  opacity: .4;
  cursor: default
}

.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]+span::after {
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.radio-s input[type="radio"]:checked+span::after {
  content: "\2022";
  font-size: 24px
}

.checkboxe-s li {
  list-style: none;
}

:root .checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span::after {
  content: "\2713";
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span::after {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: solid 2px #01A982;
  color: #01A982;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.checkboxe-s input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span::after {
  border: solid 2px #01A982;
}
```

```html
<h1>Radio</h1>
<div class="radio-s">
  <label for="radio1" class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="radio1" />
    <span class="comp-name">Radio 1</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio-s">
  <label for="radio2" class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="radio2" />
    <span class="comp-name">Radio 1</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`line-height` is the problem.

For example putting it to `14px` might fix your problem.

```
.radio-s input[type="radio"]:checked + span::after {
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

**EDIT:** I suggest that you convert your width and height of your radio circle to `14px` and then put `line-height` to `14px`. Cause it looks like it's off by `1px` cause the number 13 is odd.

Comment: Awesome its working. Does it works in IE 9, 10 as well ??

Comment: I consulted caniuse.com. It should support those browser. I do not have any near me to check tho. 

I should note that IE8 only supports pseudo selectors that use single collon. For example - 
span::after should be span:after